# Vagrantfile not loaded up in path with special characters

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to do `vagrant up` inside the following directory:

```
~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/
```

<sup>I know, I should fix my naming conventions. Can't help it right now, though.</sup>

As you can see, there are several special characters in the path, such as  *(space)*, `&`, and `.`.

The `Homestead.yaml` file contains this:

```
folders:
  -
    map: ~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/
    to: /home/vagrant/app
```

When running `vagrant up` from inside that directory, I'm seeing the following (abbreviated) error:

> There was an error loading a Vagrantfile.
>   Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/linusgeffarth/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb

Yes, `Vagrantfile` exists in this directory. I copied the path into terminal to verify.

I tried the following paths in `Homestead.yaml`:

```
map: ~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/
map: ~/Desktop/Apps&Co./company/MyApp/Backend/
map: ~/Desktop/AppsCo/company/MyApp/Backend/
map: ~/Desktop/Apps\ \&\ Co./company/My\ App/Backend/
map: '~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/'
map: "~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/"
```

Any idea how I can use the special chars path and get `vagrant up` to run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this.

1. Move the directory to some path without special characters, such as `~/Desktop` in this case.
2. Update the `Homestead.yaml` file and insert the new path: `map: ~/Desktop/Backend/app`
3. now, `cd` into the new directory and run `$ vagrant up`
4. `$ vagrant ssh` should also work now
5. `$ cd app` - try to call an API method
6. `$ exit`
7. `$ vagrant halt`
8. move the directory to the desired path
9. `cd` into the new directory, edit the `Homestead.yaml` file: `map: ~/Desktop/Apps & Co./company/My App/Backend/` (no escapes, nothing)
10. `$ vagrant up`
11. `$ vagrant ssh`
12. `$ cd app`

Now it should work in the desired directory.